# Couldn't create model.tar.gz file while training scikit learn model in AWS Sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I want to create an endpoint for scikit logistic regression in AWS Sagemaker. I have a `train.py` file which contains training code for scikit sagemaker.

```
import subprocess as sb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle,json
import sys

def install(package):
    sb.call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])

install('s3fs')

import argparse
import os

if __name__ =='__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # hyperparameters sent by the client are passed as command-line arguments to the script.
    parser.add_argument('--solver', type=str, default='liblinear')

    # Data, model, and output directories
    parser.add_argument('--output_data_dir', type=str, default=os.environ.get('SM_OUTPUT_DIR'))
    parser.add_argument('--model_dir', type=str, default=os.environ.get('SM_MODEL_DIR'))
    parser.add_argument('--train', type=str, default=os.environ.get('SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN'))

    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

    # ... load from args.train and args.test, train a model, write model to args.model_dir.

    input_files = [ os.path.join(args.train, file) for file in os.listdir(args.train) ]
    if len(input_files) == 0:
        raise ValueError(('There are no files in {}.\n' +
                          'This usually indicates that the channel ({}) was incorrectly specified,\n' +
                          'the data specification in S3 was incorrectly specified or the role specified\n' +
                          'does not have permission to access the data.').format(args.train, "train"))

    raw_data = [ pd.read_csv(file, header=None, engine="python") for file in input_files ]

    df = pd.concat(raw_data)

    y = df.iloc[:,0]
    X = df.iloc[:,1:]



    solver = args.solver
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    lr = LogisticRegression(solver=solver).fit(X, y)
from sklearn.externals import joblib
def model_fn(model_dir):
    lr = joblib.dump(lr, "model.joblib")
    return lr
```

In my sagemaker notebook I ran the following code

```
import os
import boto3
import re
import copy
import time
from time import gmtime, strftime
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
import sagemaker

role = get_execution_role()

region = boto3.Session().region_name

bucket=<bucket> # Replace with your s3 bucket name
prefix = <prefix>

output_path = 's3://{}/{}/{}'.format(bucket, prefix,'output_data_dir')
train_data = 's3://{}/{}/{}'.format(bucket, prefix, 'train')
train_channel = sagemaker.session.s3_input(train_data, content_type='text/csv')

from sagemaker.sklearn.estimator import SKLearn
sklearn = SKLearn(
    entry_point='train.py',
    train_instance_type="ml.m4.xlarge",
    role=role,output_path = output_path,
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker.Session(),
    hyperparameters={'solver':'liblinear'})
```

I'm fitting my model here

```
sklearn.fit({'train': train_channel})
```

Now, for creating endpoint,

```
from sagemaker.predictor import csv_serializer
predictor = sklearn.deploy(1, 'ml.m4.xlarge')
```

While trying to create endpoint, it is throwing

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateModel operation: Could not find model data at s3://<bucket>/<prefix>/output_data_dir/sagemaker-scikit-learn-x-y-z-000/output/model.tar.gz.
```

I checked my S3 bucket. Inside my `output_data_dir` there is `sagemaker-scikit-learn-x-y-z-000` dir which has `debug-output\training_job_end.ts` file. An additional directory got created outside my `<prefix>` folder with name `sagemaker-scikit-learn-x-y-z-000` that has `source\sourcedir.tar.gz` file. Generally whenever I trained my models with sagemaker built-in algorithms, `output_data_dir\sagemaker-scikit-learn-x-y-z-000\output\model.tar.gz` kind of files get created. Can someone please tell me where my scikit model got stored, how to push `source\sourcedir.tar.gz` inside my prefix code without having doing it manually and how to see contents of `sourcedir.tar.gz`?

Edit: I elaborated the question regarding `prefix`. Whenever I run `sklearn.fit()`, two files with same name `sagemaker-scikit-learn-x-y-z-000` are getting created in my S3 bucket. One created inside my `<bucket>/<prefix>/output_data_dir/sagemaker-scikit-learn-x-y-z-000/debug-output/training_job_end.ts` and other file is created in `<bucket>/sagemaker-scikit-learn-x-y-z-000/source/sourcedir.tar.gz`. Why is the second file not created inside my `<prefix>` like the first one? What is contained in `sourcedir.tar.gz` file?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your model is really stored, if you can't find it in S3. While you define a function with the call of joblib.dump in your entry point script, I am having the call at the end of the main. For example:

```
# persist model
path = os.path.join(args.model_dir, "model.joblib")
joblib.dump(myestimator, path)
print('model persisted at ' + path)
```

Then the file can be found in ..\output\model.tar.gz just as in your other cases. In order to double-check that is created you maybe want to have a print statement that can be found in the protocol of the training.

Comment: Please explain further your question with the prefix code.

Comment: Could you explain how this will create a file in the required tar.gz format (which Sagemaker needs to deploy the SKLearn model)?

Answer (score 0):

You must dump the model as the last step of your training code. Currently you are doing it in the wrong place, as model_fn goal is to load the model for inference, not for training.

1. Add the dump after training:

   ```
   lr = LogisticRegression(solver=solver).fit(X, y)
   lr = joblib.dump(lr, args.model_dir)
   ```
2. Change model_fn() to load the model instead of dumping it.

See more [here](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_sklearn.html).

Comment: Could you explain how this will create a file in the required tar.gz format (which Sagemaker needs to deploy the SKLearn model)?

Comment: When running a training job, artifacts saved to args.model_dir are automatically tar.gz by sagemaker and are the resulting model artifact of the training job. The same model artifact is the input to an inference endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

This post here explains it well:
https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-a-pre-trained-sklearn-model-on-amazon-sagemaker-826a2b5ac0b6

In short, the tar.gz gets created by tar-gz-ing the model.joblib binary which was first created joblib.dump. To quote the article:

```
#Build tar file with model data + inference code
bashCommand = "tar -cvpzf model.tar.gz model.joblib inference.py"
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
```

The inference.py is probably optional.